# Was Ren referring to Clone Troopers?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, Kylo Ren asks the General at one point whether he should send some clones rather than the General's Stormtroopers to which the General was outraged. **Was Ren referring to Clone Troopers (as in from the Clone Wars) or something else?**

Comment: Feel free to add spoiler tags if you feel it's necessary!

Comment: I mean... what else could he possibly be referring to?

Comment: @RedCaio that's what I thought at first, but we see no other evidence of clone troopers existing as soldiers past the Clone Wars (to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: Use of clones [stopped soon after the Clone Wars](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11432/4830). In the EU ("Legends") clones appeared on occasion. Due to various issues, it's unlikely that many if any would be alive by the time of TFA. New ones could exist, of course; it seems reasonable that groups like the First Order would want to capitalize on troops for money.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, he seems to be referring to Clone Troopers

In that scene, Kylo Ren seems to be questioning the loyalty and effectiveness of the general's storm troopers, who are apparently now taken at birth and trained rather than being clones.  Kylo Ren is suggesting that the supreme leader should consider a clone army instead of non-clones.

It seems like the scene has two purposes:

1. To explain to us that General Hux's storm troopers aren't clones.
2. To show the tension between Kylo Ren and General Hux.

It's interesting that the storm troopers aren't clones because in the battle at Maz's place, one of the storm troopers seems to recognize Finn.  I had assumed for a moment that they *were* clones, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  In fact, this unit working with Kylo Ren (and Phasma) would all have known each other, so it makes sense that he would be recognized.

What I don't think is clear (from the movie) is whether *any* First Order storm troopers are clones.  The only thing that's clear is that General Hux's storm troopers are the product of some kind of from-birth-programming training program.

Comment: It is unlikely that any of them are clones. In the Disney cartoon, *Star Wars Rebels*, it's mentioned that the Galactic Empire discontinued using Clones early on because they were no longer necessary.

Answer (score 6):

There is no canon details to illuminate this explicitly, but the context of the conversation was the loyalty (or lack thereof) of the troops after FN-2187's defection - despite Hux's patented special indoctrination training program (tm).

Hux says `I won't have you question my methods!` right before Ren's comeback.

As such, Ren was most likely referring to the full loyalty and obedience of Clone Wars/Early Empire era GAR clones, and putting down Hux's methods which he disagrees with (programming from early age, indoctrination and simulations - those are covered in detail in *Visual Dictionary* and *Before the Awakening* books).

> **A rival of Kylo Ren’s**, Hux eagerly awaits the day when the First Order will bring down the hated New Republic, and considers it his destiny to rule the galaxy. (*[Hux@Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/general-hux)*)
>
> Hux's experiences in warfare are entirely theoretical. Few would question the thoroughness or complexity of his simulations, **but Kylo Ren in particular has little respect for Hux as a warrior** (*Visual Dictionary*, p.40).

Please note that this may also mean **absolutely nothing** and may simply be Kylo Ren as usual losing his teenage Emo temper and just lashing out with a witty insult to Hux, who he can't stand as per *Visual Dictionary*. Sometimes a *Awe-SNAP* remark is just an *Awe-SNAP* remark.

Here's the dialog from WGA script:

```
GENERAL HUX
Supreme Leader Snoke was explicit.
Capture the droid if we can, but
destroy it if we must.
KYLO REN
How capable are your soldiers,
General?
GENERAL HUX
(with vitriol)
I won't have you question my methods.
KYLO REN
They're obviously skilled at
committing high treason. Perhaps
Leader Snoke should consider using a
clone army.
GENERAL HUX
(you son-of-a-bitch)
My men are exceptionally trained --
programmed from birth--
KYLO REN
Then they should have no problem
retrieving the droid. Unharmed.
```

Comment: @ScottWhitlock - WGA script

Comment: Does he say "you son of a bitch" in the movie?

Comment: @TZHX - Not sure. Ask on the main site (may be *** out the swear word) in case someone knows :)  However, that seems to be more of a subvocal mood direction to me, but I'm not an expert on scripts