# Why are First Order Stormtroopers not clones anymore?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

In *Episode II*, they showed that stormtroopers were a request from Sifo-Dyas to create the clone army based on Jango Fett.

Why are the clones not being used in the First Order?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41198/what-canon-evidence-is-there-that-stormtroopers-are-are-not-still-clones

Comment: Creating clones is expensive, while grabbing kids from around the galaxy and indoctrinating them is free!

Comment: I agree this is a dupe, but not of that question. This question is 'why did they do it' that one is 'did they do it.' This question here answers why they did it https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11432/110291