# How did skilled Clonetroopers transition to incompetent Stormtroopers?

Tags: star-wars

When the Clonetroopers were working for the Jedi, they were dedicated, clever, and personable, whereas the Imperial Stormtroopers come off as bungling, uncoordinated drones with poor aim. Granted, as the original clones are presumably replaced by individual recruits over time, the people within the army will change. But is there any in-universe rationale given for the decline of the Grand Army's originally high standards?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, but can't find the original now

Comment: They seemed to carry out the assault on the initial blockade runner in ep IV and the assault on Hoth pretty competently...

Comment: this http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/are-all-stormtroopers-as-poor-soldiers-as-the-ones-in-the-movies . is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Specifically, [Raphael's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11415/5184) discusses this.

Comment: Actually, even more direct clone: [Why Did the Empire Discontinue the Clone Trooper Program?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11432/why-did-the-empire-discontinue-the-clone-trooper-program/11470).

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stormtrooper tells us that they stopped using Fett clones when Kamino rebelled and started recruiting regular people in to the Stormtrooper Corps

Answer (score 1):

The reason they became incompetence is because the clones made were firstly second generation clones which were based on dna obtained from the clones of the original jango fett so there is dna loss. secondly they were made in Spaarti cloning cylinders which is a 3 day cloning process, not allowing the clones appropriate time to be trained and have there cognition skills developed.